# How to do partition the hard drive while installing ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

Hi Can any one help on partitioning the hard drive(disk partitioning) while installing Ubuntu, i am unable to find the option.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307229/how-can-i-create-a-separate-data-partition/307258#307258), it might help.

Comment: You do it in the installer before you start installing Ubuntu, check for Something similar to customize or so.