# Is there a good reason to have separate /home and data partitions?

Tags: partitioning

I want to make the switch from W7/Ubuntu dual boot to (K)Ubuntu as my only OS when 14.04 is released, but I'm unsure about how to partition my HDD. The general consensus for a good desktop PC partition scheme seems to be around 15--20 GB for  `/`, 1.1*RAM for `swap` and the rest for `/home` (...right?).

I will be working with some big data sets that I'd like to keep separate from my system. For that reason I thought about keeping `/home` small and creating a fourth `data` partition where only work related stuff goes. A few questions about that:

1. Is there a good reason not to do that and instead keep all my data in `/home`? I probably won't be jumping distros or something; this is for my work PC and I will likely stay on a 14.04 LTS for a long time.
2. If it's a good idea to have a separate `data` partition: How big should `/home` be if I don't store any data there? Or should I not make it a separate partition at all then?

Please tell me if this is a stupid idea. I just didn't find myself working in `/home` at all (mostly on network or on a data partition that I shared with Windows). But then again, `/`, `swap`, `/home` and `/`, `swap`, `data` doesn't seem to be much different apart from the fact that I don't have any linux configuration files floating around in my data backups.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307229/how-can-i-create-a-separate-data-partition) is a somewhat related question, but they don't go into detail whether or not this is a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for whatever you like.

I have my data on a /discworld partition because at work I need more than 1 operating system (RedHat, CentOS, SUSE, Ubuntu, SCO) and it is a lot easier to have all my software in that partition (I use separate /home's per install and symlink the directories to my partition).

The data is also on a 2nd disc so I can pull it out of the system and insert it elsewhere.

For a single OS it does not really matter. Nowadays installing Ubuntu can be done without loss of /home (even if it is not in a separate partition).

If you do not hibernate/suspend you can even go without a swap (my notebook has an ssd as 1st disc and boots in 15 seconds so I just turn it off when I do not need the machine).

> Please tell me if this is a stupid idea.

There are no stupid idea's when it comes to partitioning. Just what I or others believe to be sane does not make your idea stupid. Just different. Some methods we all agree on are dubious but then again...

Example: a partition for /var is not really needed for most of us. When you use MySQL /var is going to be filled with larg(ish) files so it can run full. But you can also put the SQL database elsewhere. So it might look weird at first but it is also a valid argument to store the SQL database elsewhere (like in a user partition).

Any setup will have its flaws and good points. Just make sure your setup ticks all your good points.

Comment: Thank you. :) I'll probably use a separate data partition then.